# Is there a way to extract window start time and window endtime in spark streaming windowing?

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am having a `DSTREAM` on which I use `window` method. Then subsequently I do other operations like reduceByKey. Is it possible to add the window start time and end time to the DSTREAM data and use it as a key?

consider i have a DSTREAM with the following input schema:

```
(call_id, call_duration, call_count)
```

after window operation on the DSTREAM, is it possible produce the following output?

```
(window_start_time, window_end_time, average_call_duration, total_call_counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dstream.foreachRDD((rdd, time)=> {
  // time is scheduler time for the batch job.it's interval was your window/slide length.
})
```

Use the time as the parameter of your ETL function.